# Scanner not printing correctly when printing anything else

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    readFile(console.next()); 
}

public static void readFile(String name) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("names.txt")); // Open pipe
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        String line = input.nextLine();
        scanLine(line, name);
    }
}

public static void scanLine(String line, String name) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner oneLine = new Scanner(line);
    String txtName = oneLine.next();
    System.out.println("txtName: " + txtName);
    System.out.println("name: " + name);
}
```

With Line 18 (Printing name);
Response: [Incorrect]

```
txtName: Delvin
name: A
txtName: Demarco
name: A
txtName: Demarcus
name: A
txtName: Demario
name: A
....
```

Without Line 18: 
Response: [Correct]

```
txtName: A
txtName: Aaliyah
txtName: Aaron
txtName: Abagail
txtName: Abbey
txtName: Abbie
txtName: Abbigail
txtName: Abby
txtName: Abdiel
txtName: Abdul
txtName: Abdullah
txtName: Abe
txtName: Abel
....
```

This is how the code flows:

1. User enters a String (a Name)
2. `readFile` is called, I create a new `Scanner` object and pass in a
   `new File`.
3. I want the application to keep running until it gets to the last
   line of the .txt file, so while the input has a nextLine, It'll keep
   looping.
4. I pass in the string from a single row to scanLine, and I create a
   new Scanner object for that String.
5. Each line looks like: String [Name], Int [Number], Int, Int, Int ...
6. After it finds the line which matches with the name name the user
   entered, It'd then send that line to getStats() [That's it so far.]

Problem:
For some reason, just printing the `name` variable (Line 18) oneLine.next() seems to start printing somewhere like half-way down the .txt file.

But if I don't print the name, (or don't use the name variable at all) -- It seems to work perfectly, printing the first letter `A` to the last.

Comment: What line is 18 ? System.out.println("name: " + name); ?

Comment: @CMPS Yes, line 18 is prints out `name`

Comment: So commenting this line affects the Sysout above it ? This is not possible unless I understood this incorrectly

Comment: I would use `String txtName = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' '))` to get the name

Comment: @engineer No, to your most recent comment. I've checked the entire console from top to bottom multiple times.

Comment: @CMPS That's what it seems like, which is why I'm totally confused.

Comment: @engineer The string `line` doesn't have the same value as `txtName.` line looks like: String, Int, Int, Int, Int, ...

Comment: Why did you show us `getStats`?

Comment: All I can suggest is close the Scanner, but the logic is correct

Comment: Also, is there a reason why such a large amount of data is in a txt file? Can you not use SQL?

Comment: What is the comment "`// Open pipe`" supposed to mean? Opening a file for reading is nothing like opening a pipe. And why are you using 3 `Scanner` objects? If all you want is line reading, use a `BufferedReader`. `Scanner` is very slow in comparison. And use `split()` instead of another reader to extract the first value from a line. Again, `Scanner` is very slow in comparison.

Comment: @Andreas ` Open pipe` is a personal comment for me, sorry if that bothers you. This is an exercise for a class, we aren't allowed to use `BufferedReader` or `split()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem: For some reason, just printing the name variable (Line 18) oneLine.next() seems to start printing somewhere like half-way down the .txt file.

Whether running in a Windows console or running in an IDE (like Eclipse), the output window is limited to how many lines it can show.

When you print 2 lines per line of input, you're overflowing the output window, and the first half(?) of the output get discarded. It still got printed, it just scrolled off before you saw it.

Comment: Understandable, but then how come a statement like: `if("Delvin" == txtName)` never returns true?

Comment: @AjaxjQuery Because you need to compare strings using `equals()`.